# How do I rename entries in Google Authenticator?

Tags: google-authenticator

I have about a half-dozen entries for one site. So the name usually only displays the last two letters of the account name. It's hard to figure out which account the entry is for.

How do I rename entries in Google Authenticator?

Answer (score 5):

Touch the entry you want to rename for maybe one second (until it's selected), then use the three-point-menu to rename it.

Answer (score 5):

Touch the entry you want to rename for one/two second until a an accordion appears.
On the top of the screen, you'll see edit icon (pencil) allowing you to rename the entry.
Click on the pencil and rename the entry.

Comment: The above instructions work but, on my Android-based app, at least, I am only able to change the part of the name that is in parenthesis. I have not found a way to edit the text not in parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, it can't be done. You can change the account name, but that's only the second part of the name. The first part is fixed and can't be changed. The problem with this is many use a sub domain and domain as the first part so you can't even see the second part (which can be changed).

Google really should fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rename application part of the entry. Only thing that I found helpful is to put the phone Font size to smallest possible, however drawback is that its a global setting and has its obvious side effects to overall usability.